# Trying To Move Folders Based On Name and Date With a Bash Script

Tags: bash

I have an archive of folders with subfolders labeled, 2012-08-29, 2012-10-10, 2012-09-01 etc., that I'm trying to archive with a bash script into folders monthly 2012-08, 2012-09, 2012-10, etc.

I was initially archiving by week but found that it would be problematic when a week would have days from 2 different months as 1 or more of the days would be archived in the wrong month's folder.

Any idea on trying to make this happen with a simple bash script?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you move the daily folders from a month `2012-08-*` to the month folder `2012-08`:

```
mv 2012-08-* 2012-08
```

Pretty simple, isn't it?